# Without specifying a port number inside of a API request how server decided that this request is for port 80 or 443

Tags: api, nginx, server, ip, port

I did not mention port number in my api end point, but how server decided to serve this request using port 80 or 443

```
const {data} = await axios.get('/api/users/currentuser');
```

Comment: Relative URLs are combined with the current page URL to create the final URL. So if the current page uses HTTPS, then the final URL will also use HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in NGINX:

```
server {
  root /var/www/html;
  
  server_name _;

# this is the react/angular fronted application endpoints
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

# this is the api endpoints
  location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

However you have not explicitely mentioned in the question that you are using NGINX or not but you have nginx in one of the 5 tags of this question, so I am supposing that you must be using NGINX and so, I am answering in that context.